Powers of imaginary numbers summing to an irrational real number
From the identities $$e^{i\pi}=-1$$$$\sin x = \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}} {2i},$$ it is quite easy to get the results $\sqrt{2}=i^{1/2} - i^{3/2}$ and $\sqrt{3}=i^{1/3} - i^{5/3}$
I found these two while playing around with Euler's Identity and Euler's formula. After getting these, I searched for more, perhaps of the form $\sqrt{p} = i^{1/p} - i^{p+k/p}$ where $p$ is a prime and $p+k$ is the prime after it. But, surprisingly, I didn't find any. Can anyone prove that these are the only identities of this form, or find some more if they can?
Edit: I now see that it is not possible for $p>3$. But, there may then exist results like $\sqrt{p} = i^{1/p} - i^{a/p} - i^{b/p} - \dots$ I am now interested in finding results of this form.
If we also bring $\tan x$ in the mix, since it has a range of all the real numbers, we do not have pesky problems like the ones faced by $\sin x$. Hence, we get $$\tan x = \frac {i^{2x/\pi} - i^{-2x/\pi}} {i(i^{2x/\pi} + i^{-2x/\pi})}$$ Though simplifying expressions like these might be tougher, it gets rid of the modulus problem.
Here's another one (kind of): $$\frac{\sqrt{5} - 1}{2} = i^{4/5} - i^{6/5}$$ This comes from $\sin \frac{\pi}{10} = \frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{4}$.
How can we somehow convert this one to the general form with $\sqrt{5}$ on one side and only $i^k$ terms on the other side?

Note that $\lvert i\rvert=1$, so the magnitude of your expression could be at most $2$

See also this

I don't understand almost any of this as I am 14 years old and still in high school.

I see.  My point is that, while the pattern you discovered doesn’t continue, it is related to an important result in (college-level) algebraic number theory that relates the square root of $\pm p$ to $e^{2\pi i/p}$; e.g., $\cos(2\pi i/5)=(\sqrt5-1)/4$

Thank you for explaining.

It's great that you're learning this stuff in 9th grade! Good job!

Your formula can’t work for $p>4$, since $\lvert i\rvert=1$ so the magnitude of your expression is at most $2$, but you might be interested in this.
